# "Can you tell me how can I use this tool?"

Tags: grammaticality

Please, what is not acceptable about this sentence:

> Can you tell me how can I use this tool?

Answer (score 1):

The sentence should say:

> Can you tell me how I **can** use this tool?

In forming questions, you should place only the first "can" before the subject. All other modal verbs like *can* should follow the declarative sentence structure. The first "can" placed before *you* already makes the sentence an interrogative one.